# How can I store datas entered in to a registration form in python-django?

Tags: python, html, django

I created a login page and a registration form using HTML.

Login.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
    <head> 

    <title>login_page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/signup.css' %}">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arial&subset=latin,latin-ext"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda+One"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    

     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<center>
  <title>Online Registration</title>    
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">      

function validate(){
    var valid = true;

    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();        

    if(email=='' || email==null)
    {
        valid=false;
        $('#email_error').html("* Please enter email.");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#email_error').html("");
    }

    if(password=='' || password==null)
    {
        valid=false;
        $('#password_error').html("* Please enter password.");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#password_error').html("");
    }

    if(valid==false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You form is ready to submit.");
        return true;
    } 
}
</script>
<body>
<br>
    <h1><center>Login Form</center></h1>       

<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();" id="form_submission_ajax">
    <table class="form-table">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <br><br>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id="f_name_error" class="error"></td>
        </tr>            

        <tr>
            <td><label>Email:</label></td>
            <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id="email_error" class="error"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Password:</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id="password_error" class="error"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <br><br>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign up</a></td>

        </tr>
    </form>      
</html>
```

Registration.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
    <head> 

    <title>login_page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/signup.css' %}">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arial&subset=latin,latin-ext"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda+One"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    

     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<center>
  <title>Online Registration</title>    
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">   

function validate(){
    var valid = true;
    var f_name = $('#f_name').val();

    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var retype_password = $('#re_password').val();

    if(f_name=='' || f_name==null)
    {
        valid=false;
        $('#f_name_error').html("* Please enter firstname.");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#f_name_error').html("");
    }

    if(email=='' || email==null)
    {
        valid=false;
        $('#email_error').html("* Please enter email.");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#email_error').html("");
    }

    if(password=='' || password==null)
    {
        valid=false;
        $('#password_error').html("* Please enter password.");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#password_error').html("");
    }

    if(retype_password=='' || retype_password==null)
    {
        valid=false;
        $('#re_password_error').html("* Please enter retype password.");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#re_password_error').html("");
    }

    if(password != retype_password)
    {
        valid=false;
        $('#re_password_error').html("* Please retype password same as password.");
    }

    if(password == retype_password)
    {
        $('#re_password_error').html("");
    } 

    if(valid==false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You form is ready to submit.");
        return true;
    } 
}
</script>
<body>
<br>
    <h1><center>Registration Form</center></h1>       

<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();" id="form_submission_ajax">
    <table class="form-table">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <br><br>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Firstname:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id="f_name_error" class="error"></td>
        </tr>            

        <tr>
            <td><label>Email:</label></td>
            <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id="email_error" class="error"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Password:</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id="password_error" class="error"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Retype Password:</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="re_password" id="re_password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id="re_password_error" class="error"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this I need to set the data entered into the registration form will be saved.And only registered users can login through the login page.
How can I set this.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import PostForm
from django.utils import timezone
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth

def register(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/register.html')

def login(request):
    context = {}
    mail = request.POST.get('email','')
    pwd = request.POST.get('password','')

    user = authenticate(username=mail, password=pwd)
    if user is not None:
        # the password verified for the user
          if user.is_active:
            context['message'] = "User is valid, active and authenticated"
            return render(request,'dashboard.html',context)

          else:
            context['message'] = "The password is valid, but the account has been disabled!"
    else:
        # the authentication system was unable to verify the username and password
          context['message'] = "The username and password were incorrect."
    return render(request, 'blog/login.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

Comment: That you've provided all the code is fine, however a [mcve] would be better, whie nobody wants to read through rundred lines of several code files.

Comment: Where is your date that you want to save ? What do you want to do with it ? Is it just for information when user has registered ?